# How does this template result in compile time optimization over runtime recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I understand the well-known example of creating a compile-time factorial calculation with templates such that recursive runtime calculations are not necessary. In such an example, all the required values for the calculations are known at compile time.

But I ran across this other example for using templates to calculate the power of a number, and I just don't get how this is an optimization over a similar runtime recursive function:

```
template<int n>
inline int power(const int& m) { return power<n-1>(m)*m;}

template<>
inline int power<1>(const int& m) { return m;}

template<>
inline int power<0>(const int& m) { return 1;}

cout << power<3>(m)<<endl;
```

Obviously, `m` cannot be known at compile time in this example. So at run time, a series of calculations will still be performed that result in essentially the same thing as `m*m*m`, right?

Is their a clear advantage to a template like this? Perhaps I am just not seeing it.

Comment: This is just a syntactic sugar to perform a runtime calculation. Personally I don't see any performance gain.

Comment: One possibility is that constant folding allows inline depth reduction  to the point you end up with a single constant and a simple assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the advantage of template metaprogramming only if you know the `X` and `Y` both at compile time. The example code:

```
template<unsigned int X, unsigned int N>
struct Power { static const unsigned int value = X * Power<X,N-1>::value; };

template<unsigned int X>
struct Power<X,0> { static const unsigned int value = 1; };
```

Usage: `Power<X,Y>::value` to determine the `X^Y`.
[Demo](http://ideone.com/vY3yPz).

In your posted code (which happens to use `template`s but not meta-programming!), only the `Y` is known at compile time and `X` is passed as runtime parameter. Which means the result also will be calculated at runtime and we have to rely on compiler based optimizations. Better to use [`std::pow(..)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) in such cases.

Comment: Fascinating! I assume the term "metaprogramming" only applies to situations when you are completely avoiding runtime cost for a particular task? hence why this term does not apply to my example but does apply to your example?

Comment: @Fellowshee, yes in the context of `template` metaprogramming (TMP) you shouldn't have runtime cost. In your example you are relying on the parameter `m`, which is passed at runtime. In my example we are having a compile time constant `value`. A good test is to use the answer of any code calculation as `template` argument e.g. `template<int N> struct X {};`; if the code `X< {your calculation} > x;` compiles fine than you have used TMP, otherwise not. For example, with my code `X<Power<5,4>::value> x;` compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that this code must be instantiated at compile time, probably giving the optimiser better chance to notice that it's just a long sequence of multiplications.

It's really mainly guesswork about the optimiser implementation. It might be better at inlining different template instantiations (because that's how templates are often used) than
at inlining recursion (where it needs to discover the stop condition statically) or unrolling loops.

Comment: Thanks; compared to the factorial example that probably everyone knows, that factorial is indeed calculated entirely a compile time such that no runtime calculation of the factorial is necessary, in which case there is a much more obvious benefit to the template, is that plausible?

Comment: @Fellowshee The factorial can also only be computed at compile time if it's factorial of a *compile-time value.* Just as you could modify this function template to compute power of compile-time values only.